# How to fix missing jsx expression container aroud literal string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expression, jsx, eslint

I have the following code for a tool tip.

```
<Tooltip
     portalClassName="HelpIcon"
     title="Have a question?"
     content={<div>We're hard at work building out a more robust help tool. In the meantime, check out the current {helpContent} on the wiki.</div>}
     centered
     trigger="click"
     placement="bottom"
     tooltipType="popover"
     >
     {helpIcon}
</Tooltip>
```

I'm getting a eslint error around

"We're hard at work building out a more robust help tool. In the meantime, check out the current {helpContent} on the wiki."

saying "Missing JSX expression container around literal string (react/jsx-no-literals)"

Is there anyway i can turn that into a string inside that div to avoid getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

```
let content = <div>We're hard at work building out a more robust help tool. In the meantime, check out the current {helpContent} on the wiki.</div>;

<Tooltip
     portalClassName="HelpIcon"
     title="Have a question?"
     content={content}
     centered
     trigger="click"
     placement="bottom"
     tooltipType="popover"
     >
     {helpIcon}
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
<Tooltip
  portalClassName="HelpIcon"
  title="Have a question?"
  content={<div>{'We're hard at work building out a more robust...'}</div>}
  centered
  trigger="click"
  placement="bottom"
  tooltipType="popover"
 >
  {helpIcon}
</Tooltip>
```

[The rule documentation](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-literals.md)